# Use the triple product rule to find partial derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Using

$$
\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right)_{z} \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \right)_{x} \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)_{y}
$$

find $ \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)_{\rho_0} $ for the wave equation $y(x,t,\rho) = y_m \sin(\omega t-kx+\rho_0)$.

I have been staring at this problem for 20 minutes now, I have not come up with any way to attack it. My issue is that I need to find the partial derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$, when I don't have such a function. All I have is $y$, and all three variables are part of the sine argument.

Comment: $m$ stands for "max". $y_m$ is just the amplitude of the wave. I'll have a look at the wiki. Yes, I copied the question.

Answer (score -1):

From [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule#Derivation):

$$dy=\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z dx+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x dz$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z +\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x \frac{dz}{dx}$$

In the same way:
$$dz=\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y dx+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_x dy$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y +\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_x \frac{dy}{dx}$$

and if we combine the two:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z +\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x \cdot \left[\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y +\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_x \frac{dy}{dx}\right]$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \left[1-\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x\cdot \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_x\right]=\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z +\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x \cdot \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y $$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z +\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x \cdot \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y}{1-\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x\cdot \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_x} $$

Now, if $y=y_m \sin(\omega t-kx+\rho _0)$, let us write:
$R(y,x,t)=y_m \sin(\omega t-kx+\rho _0)-y=0$
. Now from [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation) we can write:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}}$$

I will not finish the job. I will refer you to [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), so you can finish the job yourself.